# Android list view with empty state shrinks root view

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, empty-list

Hi I am developing Android application in which I am using list view with dialog fragment. I also tried to set empty view for my list view. Everything works fine, only my list view get shrink after showing empty view. I tried it in following ways:

```
    View emptyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.no_result_found_layout, null, false);
    ViewGroup viewGroup= ( ViewGroup)countryListView.getParent();
    viewGroup.addView(emptyView, countryListView.getLayoutParams());
    countryListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

I tried through xml as well.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_llt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_100"
        android:background="@color/action_bar_color"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.newActivity.views.UbuntuMediumTextView
            android:id="@+id/header_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:text="@string/select_country_hint_text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/view_padding_normal"
            android:hint="@string/search_country_hint_text"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/white_transparent"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white_transparent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"></ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_result_found"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_gray_light"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way to retain width of list view after adding empty view. Need some help. Thank you

Comment: try to set layout param to listview

Answer (score 0):

Set them in XML, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="THE LIST IS EMPTY!"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then:

```
ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourListView);
yourListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyListView));
```

Comment: I tried this as well. But same result. My list is inside dialogfragment

Comment: This should definitely work. I suspect you used incorrect layout_width/height values. Posting your XML code would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the layout params of the dialog, add this in your dialog fragment code

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        int height = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.70);
        int width = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.80);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wan to show empty view when there is no data you should set empty view to your list view

```
<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="No Results" />


listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
```

Comment: pay attention android:id="@android:id/empty"

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

> View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
>
> View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

So if you change `android:visibility="gone"` to `android:visibility="invisible"` the view will be not visible but still occupy the space.